# Where is Bea Weblogic Work Folder

Tags: oracle, jsp, weblogic, weblogic11g, temporary-directory

I know that this may be a trivial question but I really cannot find the work folder in Oracle BEA weblogic 10.3. Unlike the Apache Tomcat where it is clearly in the work directory usually under WEB-INF.

I already researched it on [JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/69202/BEA-Weblogic/Work-folder) and it said that the directory is at:

```
\bea\user_projects\domains\YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\APPLICATION_WAR
```

However, when I checked my directory, I only found the following path.

```
\bea\user_projects\workspaces\default\<project base>
```

I have been encountering error where the cache still remained for compiled JSP but I could not delete the work directory content manually. I tried to do full clean compile but it does not work.

Note:
Already tried to search for the file by monitoring the accessed file via file monitor tool. I tried to watch the processes javaw.exe and java.exe and it shows that when it tries to search for the file in a "`jsp_servlet`" folder that it could not find the file. The odd thing is the server just works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in ["Domain Configuration Files"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/domain_config/config_files.html) in *Understanding Domain Configuration*, the directories you are looking for are:

> **servers/server-name/tmp**
>
> This directory holds temporary directories and files that are created while a server instance is running. For example, a JMS paging directory is automatically created here unless another location is specified. Files in this directory must be left alone while the server is running, but may be freely deleted when the server instance is shut down.

You'll find the `servers` directory under your `domain_name` directory but I can't say where this one is located on your machine (are you using workshop or what?).

---

Oracle Weblogic Workshop should have a `.apt_src` build directory. Try to manually delete the files in this directory (this is a safe operation). I'm not 100% sure compiled JSPs go there though.

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle Workshop for Weblogic. But the domain folder is not existing. It only contains "workspaces" folder.