# NPE when trying to load a JSP in an IFrame using JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, iframe, weblogic11g

I'm trying to load a JSP into an IFrame in a JSF page, but I'm getting a weird Weblogic Exception that I'm trying to debug:

```
`####<Nov 15, 2011 1:59:58 PM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <MACHINE_NAME> <node1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1321383598271> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@14841636[app:dist module:/APP_NAME path:/APP_NAME spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jsp_servlet._jsf.*reports.*_reportlist.*jspService(*_reportlist.java:149)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)`

Everything else in the app is running great as far as the app is concerned, except for this error which appears to be coming from the Weblogic Server itself. Has any one else seen this error, and what was the resolution to your issue?

**UPDATE**
I'm running Weblogic 11g on Windows, and using the JSF jar that is included with Weblogic, 2.0 spec I believe.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NullPointerException at jsp_servlet._jsf.reports._reportlist.jspService(_reportlist.java:149)

That error is not coming from weblogic itself. That is coming from your `reportlist.jsp`. You were using old fashioned *scriptlets* to write Java code in that JSP file instead of in a normal (and more easy debuggable/testable) Java class. Some object is `null` while the code is trying to access it.

That error is also not related to JSF. You would have exactly the same problem when you copy the iframe's URL straight into the browser's address bar.

Look at line 149 of the `_reportlist.java` file in `/jsp_servlet/_jsf/_reports` folder of Weblogic's work folder, track this back to the source code of the `reportlist.jsp` file in your public webcontent and fix it accordingly.

Comment: The page does have scriptlets in it, however line 149 in the reportList.jsp is the closing tag of a <c:foreach/> loop. The page is a legacy piece of code, and I have been instructed to not change the look and feel of the site (hence the <iframe/>) so I thought I might try to reuse it in the new project. I'm not a fan of scriptlets myself, looks like I'll have to rewrite the page after all.

Comment: Please note that line 149 is of the generated `_reportlist.java` file, not of `reportlist.jsp`. Read the last paragraph of my answer once again.

Comment: I checked, and no _reportlist.java can be found. I did however find the corresponding _reportlist.class. I'll decompile this to get more info. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: OK, if you keep in mind that it won't necessarily return as line 149 after decompiling. You may find this related question interesting as to locating the Java source files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760069/where-is-bea-weblogic-work-folder I don't use Weblogic, so I can't tell from own experience.